# UITextField not saving text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a view with several `UITextFields` in it.  I also have a high level `UISegmentController` that changes the view.  When I enter text in a field, then press the hide keyboard button, then change segemnents, it saves fine.  But when I enter text, and don't press the release keyboard button, then switch segments, it does not save the text.

How can I fix this?

Here is some of the code for the `UITextField` in my custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
- (IBAction)col2_doubleValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSString *newValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", self.col2_doubleEntryValue_1.text, self.col2_doubleEntryValue_2.text];
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [result setValue:self.row_key forKey:@"row_key"];
    [result setValue:@"1" forKey:@"column"];
    [result setValue:newValue forKey:@"col2_value"];
    [[self delegate] editDidFinish:result];
    [[self delegate] valueChanged];
}

- (IBAction)col2_singleValueEditDidBegin:(id)sender
{
}
```

[image]

Edit:

```
- (void)valueChanged
{
    self.dirtyFlag = 1;
}

- (int)saveDataToServer
{
    [self.tableView resignFirstResponder];

    if (!dirtyFlag) {
        return 0;
    }    

    NSString *errors = [DataSource updatePatientWorkflowClinicalChecklistForAppointment:[[[DrChronoDataSource getCurrentAppointment] valueForKey:@"appointment_id"] intValue] clinicalInfo:self.clinicalChecklist checklistId:[self.clinicalChecklistId intValue] patientWorkflowServerId:patientWorkflowServerId];

    if ((NULL == errors) || ![errors isEqualToString: @""]) {
        //Show error messages.
        if (NULL == errors) {
            errors = @"Failed to save data to server.  Please retry.";
        }
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Status" message:errors delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return -1;
    } else {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];
    }

    self.dirtyFlag = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the code you use to handle and store the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you link both events to the same action? Maybe you could make a BOOL in your header file called needsSaving. Set it to NO every time editing begins, then YES every time the data is saved successfully. Then only execute the body of your saving methods if needsSaving is NO, that will avoid unnecessary saving. I think doing this would simplify this function of your app. i.e.

```
- (IBAction)col2_singleValueEditDidBegin:(id)sender {
    needsSaving = YES;
}

- (int)saveDataToServer
{
    [self.tableView resignFirstResponder];

    if (!dirtyFlag || !needsSaving) {
        return 0;
    }

    NSString *errors = [DataSource updatePatientWorkflowClinicalChecklistForAppointment:[[[DrChronoDataSource getCurrentAppointment] valueForKey:@"appointment_id"] intValue] clinicalInfo:self.clinicalChecklist checklistId:[self.clinicalChecklistId intValue] patientWorkflowServerId:patientWorkflowServerId];

    if ((NULL == errors) || ![errors isEqualToString: @""]) {
        //Show error messages.
        if (NULL == errors) {
            errors = @"Failed to save data to server.  Please retry.";
        }
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Status" message:errors delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return -1;
    } else {
        needsSaving = NO;
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];
    }

    self.dirtyFlag = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any writing functions.

```
- (IBAction)col2_doubleValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSString *newValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", self.col2_doubleEntryValue_1.text, self.col2_doubleEntryValue_2.text];
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [result setValue:self.row_key forKey:@"row_key"];
    [result setValue:@"1" forKey:@"column"];
    [result setValue:newValue forKey:@"col2_value"];

    /* your aren't writing the new data anywhere, 
       you need to add something like this: 
     */

    [result writeToFile: @"somefile.txt" atomically: YES];

    [[self delegate] editDidFinish:result];
    [[self delegate] valueChanged];
}
```

Comment: The `valueChanged` method triggers a method in another class called `- (int)saveDataToServer` which saves the data.  Everything works fine when I release the keyboard with the button, but sometimes uses don't press it and just switch views so the text is then not saved.  I added this method to question

Comment: That portion of the code wasn't available when I posted my answer.

Comment: Yah, I just added it a minute ago.

Comment: try posting the `updatePatientWorkflowClinicalChecklistForAppointment` source, because none of the code you posted shows how you "save" data, where you save it to, nor why it wouldn't be saving.

Comment: All that method does is pass the data to the server.  That method is fine, the issue is that the text in the textField is not being saved therefore it is not getting passed to that method if the keyboard is not released.

Comment: Try adding your textField as an object, instead of using **just** IB. Point the IBOutlet to your textField and reference it in your code somewhere. Also, use **`NSLog`** to see at each point what the value of the textField is. Most likely it's going to be **null** all the way through.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are not implementing the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) prototocols.

Comment: That is to say, not completely :)